# Hadoop MapReduce Errors Different Data Types

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Two problems occur in the mapreduce program

1. `java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`
2. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`

I've set map output key and value class as found on other posts but still couldn't solve these two problems. For the second problem I specifically tested the set of code in map which is causing the problem and it was correct in a simple file read program.

For reference this is full output of problem 1

```
Error: java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.append(IFile.java:194)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombineOutputCollector.collect(Task.java:1350)
at peoplemail.DomainGenderCount$ReduceClass.reduce(DomainGenderCount.java:52)
at peoplemail.DomainGenderCount$ReduceClass.reduce(DomainGenderCount.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$OldCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1615)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1637)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1489)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:460)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

and this is the full output of problem 2

```
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at peoplemail.DomainGenderCount$MapClass.map(DomainGenderCount.java:34)
    at peoplemail.DomainGenderCount$MapClass.map(DomainGenderCount.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

**Data**
This is few lines of csv file I'm procesing

```
18,Daveen,Cupitt,dcupitth@last.fm,6288608483,Female
19,Marney,Eskell,meskelli@nifty.com,8164369834,Female
20,Teri,Yitzhak,tyitzhakj@bloglovin.com,2548784310,Female
21,Alain,Niblo,aniblok@howstuffworks.com,5195420924,Male
22,Vin,Creevy,vcreevyl@sfgate.com,8574528831,Female
23,Ermina,Pena,epenam@mediafire.com,2236545787,Female
24,Chrisy,Chue,cchuen@google.com,9455751444,Male
25,Morgen,Izakof,mizakofo@noaa.gov,8031181365,Male
```

**MapClass**

```
public static class MapClass 
extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable  key,Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter r)throws IOException{

        String fields[] = value.toString().split(",");
        String gender = fields[5];
        String domain = fields[3].split("@")[1];
        output.collect(new Text(domain), new Text(gender));
    }

}
```

**ReduceClass**

```
public static class ReduceClass 
extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> value,
            OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter r)throws IOException{

        int count=0;
        while(value.hasNext()){
            value.next();
            count++;
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(count));

    }

}
```

**run method**

```
public int run(String[] paths) throws Exception {

    JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(getConf(), DomainGenderCount.class);

    jobConf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    jobConf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    jobConf.setJobName("Number of Users in each domain:");

    jobConf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    jobConf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    jobConf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    jobConf.setReducerClass(ReduceClass.class);
    jobConf.setCombinerClass(ReduceClass.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, new Path(paths[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, new Path(paths[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(jobConf);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my call to hadoop

```
hadoop jar C:\Users\suman\Desktop\domaingendercount.jar /Data/people.csv /Data/Output/
```

The input file I tested with this small program

```
package peoplemail;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file  = new File("C:\\Users\\suman\\Desktop\\people.csv");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while (null != (line=bufferedReader.readLine())) {
            String fields[] = line.split(",");
            String gender = fields[5];
            String domain = fields[3].split("@")[1];
            System.out.println(domain + " " + gender);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }

}
```

This code ran correct.

These files contain all the code, data and output from hadoop.

[DomainGenderCount.java](https://pastebin.com/LbRxCHjx)

[people.csv](https://pastebin.com/NxZfYYVu)

[output log](https://pastebin.com/ZqxMFxJH)

Answer (score 3):

Your array fields[] would have 5 elements and index start from 0 and since the length of fields is 5, fields[5] is giving "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Here is the corrected mapper,

```
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
@Override
    public void map(LongWritable  key,Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter r)throws IOException{

    String fields[] = value.toString().split(",");
    String domain = fields[3].split("@")[1];
    String gender = fields[5];
    output.collect(new Text(domain), new Text(gender));
}
```

}

Comment: There are 6 fields: Id, fname, lname,email, phone, gender. Please check, as I said in my post that it works if I do it in simple java, the same map function logic.

Comment: Okay. Even if its six. The gender is at 5th location and domain is at 3rd position

Comment: I corrected the error that you pointed out but both the problems still exist, I also added the test program I wrote.

Comment: I have fixed the `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception, turns out it was input file that had missing data. But the first problem still remains. I have updated the `people.csv` file also.